# Type alias in Scala

Tags: scala, types, type-alias

I have a task where I should implement some functions operating by type alias:

```
   /**
   * We represent a set by its characteristic function, i.e.
   * its `contains` predicate.
   */
  override type FunSet = Int => Boolean
```

but I don't understand what it means. How can we represent a set by its characteristic? Namely, how it works? I have a function that checks a presence of element:

```
   /**
   * Indicates whether a set contains a given element.
   */
  def contains(s: FunSet, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)
```

I don't have an idea what it checks? For instance, I need to implement function that creates a singletone set:

```
   /**
   * Returns the set of the one given element.
   */
  def singletonSet(elem: Int): FunSet = elem == ???
```

but I can't realize what I should create?

Comment: I think you deeply misunderstand. Nothing is saved.

Comment: What does it check?

Comment: I think this is part of an exercise of implementing `Sets` in terms of `Functions`, is that right? If so, you may want to edit your question to include more details and being more clear with your question, since now it doesn't make sense at all and is not clear what your questions had to do with type aliases at all.

Comment: Sorry for my not clear explanation of the problem, I edited my question.

Comment: SO is not the place to ask for your homeworks ;) If you don't understand the exercise, maybe ask your teammates or teacher?

Comment: The idea of the exercise is to represent a set as a function which tells you if an element is present in the set. Thus the singleton set of `x` can be represented with a function that returns `true` for `x` and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is confused and confusing. What is `singletonType` and what does type aliasing have to do with singletons?

```
type FunType = Int => Boolean
```

`FunType` is now just a (slight) abbreviation for the longer correct type. (Which is, itself, a convenience form of the type `Function1[Int,Boolean]`.)

You can create values of that type.

```
val isOdd: FunType = _ % 2 > 0
```

And you can create methods that receive values of that type.

```
def applyTest(n: Int, f: FunType):Boolean = f(n)
applyTest(77, isOdd)  //true
```

And so on. It's just a type like any other.